# How to know if I am iterating on the last index of _.map()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

using a map() or _.map() in underscore instead of for loop, how should I know that I am iterating on which index or if it is an object how should I know that I am iterating over the very last remaining element?

```
_.map(ARRAY, function(data) {
   // if it is the last element left, return something...  
})
```

Comment: the second argument you pass to the function is the index. In both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_.map(ARRAY, function(data, index) {

   if(index == ARRAY.length -1) {
     // do your special thing
   }
})
```

Comment: thanks, it should be mentioned in the underscore and loadash documentation.

Comment: It is there... you just gotta look for it: "Creates an array of values by running each element in collection thru iteratee. The iteratee is invoked with three arguments:
(value, index|key, collection)."